# Questions seem trickier and trickier

Tags: discussion, questions, question-difficulty

Is the level of the questions getting higher and higher?
Or is it about my own personal level?

Comment: Even by MSO standards, this is pretty subjective. It depends on your personal knowledge, your overall browsing behavior, which tags you follow, which specific questions you read....

Comment: Could it be [the recent homepage changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)?

Comment: Maybe you're just getting dumber?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its a case of questions getting more difficult. I've found that most of the questions I need to find answers to have already been asked. As the site gets more mature, the questions are going to get more niche as the more "mainstream" questions were asked when the site was young.

I don't see this as a my personal knowledge level being lower than other people, I see it as a natural progression of the site to include more specialised questions to compliment the generic questions that have already been asked.

Comment: Also, more people answer questions, and the probability that someone provides a more relevant answer than an "average" answerer gets higher...